# How to disable all forms fields from submission in rails (Not with jQuery)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, forms

I have a form which is for nested associated tables. which mean like this figure.
[image]

So my create form will be like this

```
form_for @A_hash do |f|
   <% f.text_field :id %>
   .....
   ....
   ....
   ....
     f.B each do |g|
         <% text_field_tag :for_C, :value => g.id %>
         .......
         .......
         .......
         .......
     end
end
```

Which rends in front end like this

```
<form >
  <tr>
   <td><input val...></td><td><input val...></td>.....
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input val...></td><td><input val...></td>.....
  </tr>
.......
.......
.......
.......
</form>
```

so in this i need to disable one complete iteration from submission.

**Note:** 
Please don not suggest Jquery method and i already did it. I just wants to know will it be done in rails way or not.

**EDIT**:
Respective of some values from hash i wants to disable some field either all field or only from B's iteration. Any way? Because it will decrease my work from front end. since i have many input and select fields apart from form in my view i need to hand it properly.

Comment: What exactly do you mean? Since there are many B's, do you want to show only a few of these or do you mean something else?

Comment: @BryanOemar Thanks for concern. and please Look at my edit i have explained it properly now.

Comment: I still don't quite follow I think. Wouldn't an if condition take care of this? Since you know on which values you'd like to disable/hide a form. 

Perhaps you could give a concrete example with the values you'd like to filter out?

Comment: What  version of rails are you using? Are you using Strong Parameter?

Comment: rails -v 3, and sorry i am not allowed to install new gems. Is there any other way..?